# How to get the size of a row for a View in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to calculate the average size of a row for a view. Is there any table/view which stores that information in oracle.

Like for tables, avg_row_len is available in all_tables table. Is there anything exist for View.

I can calculate manually but I have to do it in a stored procedure and it will become very complex in stored procedure.

Comment: Views are not stored.

Comment: So there is no way I can get that information from somewhere?

Comment: Which information?

Comment: Why would you need to know this in the first place?  `avg_row_len` is used by the optimizer to estimate the cost of a query (thus it may be wildly inaccurate if statistics on the table are stale).  Presumably, you're not writing a query optimizer so I'm hard-pressed to guess why you'd even want to know that in the first place.  You could create a new table to store the average row lengths and do the calculation overnight but that seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Run `CREATE TABLE some_dummy_table AS SELECT * FROM view`, then get avg_row_len of that dummy table, then drop the table.